# Storing Data to MySQL database from html form with checkboxes

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have an html form with checkboxes and I managed to store the values using an array to my database .

I added a name field to the form, and added a column on mysql table .

**The problem is,** the newly added name field is not storing any values and is malfunctioning the previous code. I'm pretty sure my definition for the `$fname` value is incorrect, here is the full php code

```
$dbcon = mysqli_connect("$host","$username","$password","$db_name") ;           

        if (!$dbcon) {
        die('error connecting to database'); }

        echo 'Courses successfully registerd , ' ;  

    // escape variables for security
    $studentid = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_GET['studentid']);
    $fname = $_POST["name"]; 

// Get Cources
$name = $_GET['ckb'];
if(isset($_GET['ckb']))
{
foreach ($name as $courcess){
$cc=$cc. $courcess.',';
}
}

    //$ckb = join (', ', var_dump($_POST['ckb'])); 


    $sql="INSERT INTO courses (studentid, ckb)
    VALUES ('$studentid', '$cc', $fname)";

    if (!mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($dbcon));
}
echo "  Thank you for using IME Virtual Registeration  ";   
        mysqli_close($dbcon);
?>
```

Comment: You're specifying that you're providing 2 columns, but actually provide 3? `INSERT INTO courses (studentid, ckb) VALUES ('$studentid', '$cc', $fname)`

Comment: Had you error reporting "on", it would have signaled a mismatch set of values/columns.

Comment: Thanks ! that's it for sure , however I'm getting file not found after uploading the fixed connect-mysql.php file...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 $sql="INSERT INTO courses (studentid, ckb)
VALUES ('$studentid', '$cc', $fname)";
```

is your problem.  You are attempting to insert three values into two fields.  You need to add your new field after ckb so that the argument $fname can be inserted into it.